# How to add attributes to JSON array using javascripts?

Tags: javascript, json, arrays

I want to construct following JSON dynamically using Javascript.

```
{    
    "Events": [{
        "Name": "Code Change",
        "Enabled": "true",
        "Properties": [{
            "Name": "url",
            "Value": "val"
        }]
    }],
    "Properties": [{
        "Name": "url",
        "Value": "val"
    }]    
}
```

So i wrote following code but it creates JSON object where Name, Enabled and properties under separate curly brackets. Is there anyway to resolve this issue instead of using push method?

**Code**

```
var eventProperties="[{'Name':'url','Value':'val'}]";
var subscriptionProperties="[{'Name':'url','Value':'val'}]";

var eventArray = JSON.parse('[1, 5, "false"]');
var subArray = JSON.parse('[1, 5, "false"]');


var subscription = {
    Events: [],
    Properties: []
};

if(eventName != null && eventName != "") {
    subscription.Events.push({
        "Name" : eventName
    });
}

var index = 0;

if(eventEnabled != null && eventEnabled != "") {
    subscription.Events.push({
        Enabled: eventEnabled
    });
}

if(eventProperties != null && eventProperties != "") {
    subscription.Events.push({
        "Properties": eval('(' + eventProperties + ')')
    });
} 

if(subscriptionProperties != null && subscriptionProperties != "") {
    subscription.Properties = eval('(' + subscriptionProperties + ')');
}
```

**Output given**

```
{    
    "Events": [{
        "Name": "Code Change"
     },
     {
        "Enabled": "true"
     },
     {
        "Properties": [{
            "Name": "url",
            "Value": "val"
        }]
     }],    
     "Properties": [{
         "Name": "url",
         "Value": "val"
     }]
}
```

Comment: You *really* shouldn't use `eval` in your code.

Comment: You seem to be confused. JSON is a string.

Comment: @isomarcte why i should not use eval?

Comment: @naomik Yes its a string and i wanted to build as i have mentioned. Anyway question has been sorted by an answer, thanks for response :)

Comment: @TharikKanaka See this article, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval, particularly the section called "Don't use eval needlessly!". Essentially the `eval` function opens a very simple gateway for malicious code to be injected into your code. Moreover, it is a very slow way to translate a `string` into a JavaScript value, there are almost always faster, better, safer, ways than using `eval`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is. You need to create only one object like so.

```
subscription.Events.push({
    Name: eventName,
    Enabled: eventEnabled,
    Properties: JSON.parse(eventProperties)
 });
```

Or using the current flow you have:

```
 var subscription = {};

 var eventObject = {};

 if(eventName != null && eventName != "") {
     eventObject.Name = eventName;
 }

 if(eventEnabled != null && eventEnabled != "") {
     eventObject.Enabled = eventEnabled;
 }

 if(eventProperties != null && eventProperties != "") {
     eventObject.Properties = JSON.parse(eventProperties);
 }

 subscription.Events = [eventObject];

 if(subscriptionProperties != null && subscriptionProperties != "") {
     subscription.Properties = JSON.parse(subscriptionProperties);
 }
```

Comment: Actually i cannot create all 3 attributes like that, based on a condition i have to add attributes dynamically. it may contain all 3 or 2 or even 1 attribute